# Shrinking buffers dynamically

Tags: webgl

I am updating existing WebGl code (with only very basic knowledge about WebGl).
In the code there are a couple of functions to grow a set of buffers like this

```js
this.tail = new Float32Array(0);
this.tail_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
this.tail_index = 0;
this.tail_colors = new Float32Array(0);
this.tail_colors_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var length = 512;   
this.head = new Float32Array(0);
this.head_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
this.tail_length = new Float32Array(0);

/**
 * Update the tail buffer between two indexes.
 * @param {number} a, with a <= b
 * @param {number} b
 */
_update = function(a, b) {
    var gl = this.gl;
    var length = 512;
    var buffer = this.tail.buffer;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.tail_buffer);
    if (a == 0 && b == length - 1) {
        gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, this.tail);
    } else {
        var sublength = b - a + 1;
        for (var s = 0; s < this.solutions.length; s++)  {
            var offset = s * 3 * length * 4 + 3 * a * 4;
            var view = new Float32Array(buffer, offset, sublength * 3);
            gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, view);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Adjust all buffer sizes if needed.
 */
_grow_buffers = function() {
    function next2(x) {
        return Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(x) * Math.LOG2E));
    }
    var gl = this.gl;
    var count = next2(some_number);
    var length = 512;
    if (this.tail.length < count * length * 3) {
        var old_tail = this.tail;
        this.tail = new Float32Array(count * length * 3);
        this.tail.set(old_tail);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.tail_buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, count * length * 4 * 3, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        this._update(0, length - 1);
    }
    if (this.tail_length.length < count) {
        var old_tail_length = this.tail_length;
        this.tail_length = new Float32Array(count);
        this.tail_length.set(old_tail_length);
    }
    if (this.tail_colors.length < count * 3) {
        this.tail_colors = new Float32Array(count * 3);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tail_colors.length; i++) {
            var color = getColor(i);
            this.tail_colors[i * 3 + 0] = color[0];
            this.tail_colors[i * 3 + 1] = color[1];
            this.tail_colors[i * 3 + 2] = color[2];
        }
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.tail_colors_buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, count * 4 * 3, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, this.tail_colors);
    }
    if (this.head.length < count * 3) {
        this.head = new Float32Array(count * 3);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.head_buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, count * 3 * 4, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }
};
```

I would like to write a function that shrinks the buffers (instead of growing them as the one above). The easy way is to use a function similar to the grow_buffers function but revert the if statements (from < to >). I think I am missing something though and that might not deallocate all the buffer space.

Here are some things I dont understand in the above code: what does `gl.bufferSubData` do? In the multiplication by 3 * 4 I dont understand the 4 (the 3 is probably the number of colors)

Comment: If your knowledge is that lacking then you really need to [go read some tutorials on WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org). In answer to your questions though, `gl.bufferSubData` updates a portion of an existing buffer with new data vs `gl.bufferData` which can either (re)allocate a buffer OR both (re)allocate a buffer and upload data. Pass it a number it just (re)allocates, pass it a TypedArray is (re)allocates and uploads. 4 is the number of bytes. WebGL requires binary data so 3 colors, each color value is a 32bit float a 32bit float requires 4 bytes so count * 3 * 4 is the number of bytes.